# Should wp_postmeta meta_key always be unique for a given post_id?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-meta

I am trying to figure out a good way to establish relations between various post types.

For instance, consider a post type `lessontopic` and another post type `forumtopic`. A Lesson Topic can have several Forum Topics. But a Forum Topic only is related to one Lesson Topic.

Seems I have 3 options if I want to use meta data to keep these relations straight (I use lt = lesson topic, ft = forum topic):

1. Use a meta_value to store string of id's. This would be

```
post_id   meta_key             meta_value
lt_id     related_forumtopics  ft_id1,ft_id2,ft_id3
ft_id1    related_lessontopic  lt_id1
ft_id2    related_lessontopic  lt_id1
ft_id3    related_lessontopic  lt_id1
```

2. Use meta_key itself to store relations for one to many situation

```
post_id   meta_key                   meta_value
lt_id     related_forumtopic_ft_id1
lt_id     related_forumtopic_ft_id2
lt_id     related_forumtopic_ft_id3
ft_id1    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
ft_id2    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
ft_id3    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
```

3. Use key value pairs (where in the case of one to many like lesson topics to forum topics a given lesson topic post_id will have repeated key)

```
post_id   meta_key                   meta_value
lt_id     related_forumtopic         ft_id1
lt_id     related_forumtopic         ft_id2
lt_id     related_forumtopic         ft_id3
ft_id1    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
ft_id2    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
ft_id3    related_lessontopic        lt_id1
```

What do you think is better approach?

thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using taxonomies instead for this? In general, they perform much better than postmeta lookups

Comment: Hadn't thought of that! Worth looking into. Just that I am also trying to avoid routes that wordpress seems to create for everything imaginable. Don't want taxonomy routes. Then again rest API routes could come in handy. Lots to think about!

Comment: I previously thought that taxonomies should be for categorization. In my case, I will have many lesson topics. For instance, in a single course I will have 12 lessons, each lesson 10-15 topics. If I map topics to taxonomies in this way, will it have me getting far away from intended use? Or maybe this is case where unintended use is actually better? thanks

Comment: To be honest I just quickly overflew your question and haven't thought about your use case in depth. (And right now I don't have the time to, will come back later to your question today or tomorrow.)

Comment: Would it work to have a single hierarchical post type? So, instead of `lessontopic` and `forumtopic` you would have just `topic`. You would use the top-level, parentless topics as "lessontopics" and could have the archive only display those top-level lessontopics. Then, each `forumtopic` would simply be a child of a parent, and you could display as needed, and only link to them through their parents.